# Strange printf output in C

Tags: c, printf, output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse(char *string);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char array[10];
    array[0] = 'a';
    array[1] = 'b';
    array[2] = 'c';
    array[3] = 'd';
    array[4] = 'e';
    printf("1%s\n",array);
    char *p = reverse(array);
    printf("4%s\n",p);
    printf("5%s\n",array);
}

char * reverse(char *string)
{
    int size = strlen(string);
    char reversed[size];
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reversed[j] = string[i];
        j++;
    }
    printf("2%s\n",reversed);
    string = reversed;
    printf("3%s\n",string);
    return reversed;
}
```

This code basically just initializes an array of values and passes it into a method that reverses these values.

I am not sure if this is the best way to execute the task, since I am new to pointers and arrays in C.

But the real question is this:

Can anyone figure out why in this line

```
printf("4%s\n",p);
```

if you remove the preceding '4', so it looks like so

```
printf("%s\n",p);
```

the line won't print at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to local variable(`reversed`) in the function `reverse` the question should actually be: `Why did it work in the first place?`.

This code `string = reversed;` will only copy the pointer, and again **the local copy of the pointer** so it has no effect outside the function.

To reverse a string you don't need additional memory - this can be done in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C must end with the null character. You're using strlen on a non null-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, you just a very lucky person, because there is a serious problem with you code: you forget to add `\0` symbol at the end of string.

**UPD:** the main problem is with code line `char reversed[size];`. 
It's a regular local variable, it has automatic duration, which means that it springs into existence when the function is called and disappears when the function returns [(see this link)](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx5.html).

You need to change it to:

`char *reversed = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));`

**UPD-2:** another bug fixing will be:

1) add `array[5] = '\0';` after all other array initializing lines

2) add `reversed[j] = '\0';` after `for...loop`:

```
for(i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    reversed[j] = string[i];
    j++;
}
reversed[j] = '\0';
```

**UPD-3:** But in general it will much more correctly initialize your string in appropriate way:

```
char array[10] = "abcde";
```